# Exception in deserialization of nested objects for datamodels in loopback 4

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, loopback

In a very small loopback4 project, we tried to generate nested entities like this:

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class MySubEntity extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
  })
  mySubEntityName?: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<MySubEntity>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

@model()
export class MyMainEntity extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  id?: string;

  @property({
    type: MySubEntity,
  })
  subEntity?: MySubEntity;

  constructor(data?: Partial<MyMainEntity>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

to create the following structure (also within the document db):

```
{
  "id": "uuid123213",
  "subEntity": {
    "mySubEntityName": "Hello test"
  }
}
```

with this controller:

```
  @post('/myMainEntity', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        content: { 'application/json': { 'x-ts-type': MyMainEntity } },
      },
    },
  })
  async create(@requestBody() myMainEntity: MyMainEntity): Promise<MyMainEntity> {
    return await this.myMainEntityRepository.create(myMainEntity);
  }
```

Loopback4 compiles and starts the application. Unfortunately we get the following excepction when we try to create this object:

```
Unhandled error in POST /myMainEntity: 500 TypeError: Class constructor MySubEntity cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at MyMainEntity.set [as subEntity] (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\model-builder.js:598:81)
    at MyMainEntity.ModelBaseClass._initProperties (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\model.js:204:17)
    at MyMainEntity.ModelBaseClass (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\model.js:62:8)
    at new MyMainEntity (eval at createModelClassCtor (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)
    at Function.DataAccessObject.create (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:331:13)
    at MyMainEntitysDataSource.onConnected (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:2524:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at MyMainEntitysDataSource.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:323:12
    at C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-connector-mongodb\lib\mongodb.js:310:25
    at parseHandler (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:134:38)
    at module.exports (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:25:12)
    at C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\loopback-connector-mongodb\lib\mongodb.js:305:16
    at result (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
    at executeCallback (C:\projectOne\myMainEntity-ms\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:406:9)
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? Is there a different possibility to get a nested document structure which is typed?

I added the 'MySubEntity' after scaffolding the controller and repository (default crud)

Thank you

Comment: Could you add the controller code for the endpoint?

Comment: @angelwally , I added the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a limitation of the current implementation in loopback-datasource-juggler and/or the way how LoopBack 4 translates LB4 model definitions to Juggler models.

The error is triggered by [this code](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/5f713f03196fbd0334b0ea4f97a5d4ec608db013/lib/model-builder.js#L596-L598):

```
          // Assume the type constructor handles Constructor() call
          // If not, we should call new DataType(value).valueOf();
          this.__data[propertyName] = (value instanceof DataType) ? value : DataType(value);
```

Juggler assumes that types (models) are defined as ES5 functions which can be called either with or without `new`. However, LB4 models are implemented as ES6 classes, which must be always constructed using `new` keyword.

I think there are two options, they are not mutually exclusive:

- Fix loopback-datasource-juggler to correctly handle `DataType` functions that are ES6 class constructors. UPDATE: See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1670 for a work that's already in progress.
- Improve LB4 to convert nested LB4 models into Juggler models, similarly as we do for top-level models.

Either way, I think this is best discussed on GitHub. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2130

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `type: MySubEntity`, because I don't think loopback support this. You have 2 solutions here:

- you want your MySubEntity to be just a field in your object
  MyMainEntity then just put `object` as the type.
- you want a relation to another entity. You can create a `belongsTo`
  relation (see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html)
  but unfortunately, as far as I know it's not well implemented yet.
  You can try to handle the relation by yourself in the controller or
  the repository code and then remove the decorator `@property` from
  the field `subEntity`.

Comment: I considered those options for creating nested objects. Unfortunately a relation is not helpful for us and if we use 'object' as the type, we loose the type safety AND the request is not transformed correctly (e.g. a DATE datatype in the subcomponent will not be transformed to a date and will stay a string). 
Do you have any other idea how to deal with nested objects in loopback4?